# Sphinx - what is different between toctree and content?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, tableofcontents, toctree

I can create table of contents in two ways:

```
.. contents::
   :local:
   depth: 1
```

or as

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 1

    index
```

What is difference? Where I should use the toctree and where the contents?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`.. contents`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents) is a doctutils directive (the underlying library which defines ReST and associated utilities) and ***automatically*** generates a table of contents from headlines within the current topic.

[`.. toctree`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html) is a Sphinx-defined directive in which you **explicitly list documents** whose TOCs will be listed out.

You'd use `.. contents` for example within a document to generate an overview of contents within the page, e.g.:

```
===================
Curing World Hunger
===================

.. contents::
   :depth: 1

Abstract
========

…

Problem description
===================

…
```

You'd use `.. toctree` within an index document which contains basically nothing else:

```
=================
Scientific papers
=================

Below is a list of papers published here:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   curing_hunger
   …
```

`.. toctree` takes a list of documents to process, `.. contents` does not.